# Nuget can't resolve Entity Framework 7 dependency which is referenced in project

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, nuget, entity-framework-core

I'm currently developing a piece of software as coursework for a class and I've elected to make a Windows App and Windows Phone App. Being hit by the knowledge that Entity Framework 6 wasn't supported almost made me give up, but I started a complicated workaround with a data server before finding EF7. I figured I'd give one of the releases from GitHub a try, so I downloaded it, built the Entity Framework 7 project successfully, referenced it successfully... And hey presto, my code files are suddenly perfectly happy with their DbSet and DbContext references.

There's only a small (Actually, it's pretty big) issue that since I just imported the references, I don't have the package manager commands for updating the database and all that jazz, so I go look about to see if I've got any files that seem like they'd work for fixing that, and find a bunch of NuGet files:
[image: NuGet files]
So I add the folder to NuGet's list of places it looks and it works as expected:
[image: Picture of package manager]

The issue is, when I click install, I'm presented this:

[image: Failed install: Missing dependency for Microsoft Dependency Injection DLL]

However, this is in my references for the project:

[image: Evidence of references]

I did a bit of glancing and found that in my references, Dependency Injection seems to have no version listed unlike some of the other references, and I was thinking that might be something to do with the issue.

I've tried reimporting, rebuilding my copy of EF7, and nothing seems to work. I've no idea where to go from here and if someone could tell me what I've done wrong it'd be a great help! I've probably made some naïve mistake somewhere and I apologise in advance for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you did not link to where the Entity Framework 7 sources on GitHub are located I will assume it is  the [GitHub repository being used as part of ASP.NET vNext](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework).

The NuGet pre-release NuGet packages for ASP.NET vNext are available on [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext). If you add the following url to your existing package sources, and enable it, then the Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection pre-release NuGet package should be resolved.

https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/

Also the Entity Framework 7 pre-release NuGet packages are also available from the above package source. So you may not need to build it yourself from source code.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it importing in NuGet correctly now, and the only issue remaining is that none of the package manager commands (i.e. update-database) are working because it can't find the EntityFramework.Powershell.DLL for EF7; is there anywhere I can source this?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no EntityFramework.PowerShell.DLL for EF 7. Looking at the NuGet packages there is a EntityFramework.VisualStudio NuGet package which includes a PowerShell module that has the standard EF PowerShell commands, such as Update-Database, but there is no EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll any more.

Comment: We're still sorting out [how the commands will work in Windows Phone projects](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/579). Right now, the EntityFramework.VisualStudio package has them for Windows Desktop projects. Eventually, the EntityFramework.Commands package will have them for all supported platforms ([Design Meeting notes](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes) on this should be posted soon).

Comment: This was very helpful. The documentation on vNext is fragmentary/incomplete ... and even the blog posts I've found around EF7 all have the DbContext in the web project.  Which doesn't help if you want to update a (separate) class library from EF6 to EF7 -- i.e. when you need to install the EF7 package rather than have it provided for you by the project template.